# SQL Relation between more than 2 tables

Tags: sql, where-clause

Let's say I got a table of Clients (`tblClients`) and a table of quotes (`tblQuotes`).

To get all quotes from our existing client, I did the following:

```
SELECT q.quoteId, c.contact, q.job, 
FROM tblQuotes AS q 
INNER JOIN tblClients AS c ON q.user = c.user
```

For each quote, we got a date the quotes was created. That date is in `tblDate`. The only way I found for displaying that date is when I display my records, I do an other request like this:

```
SELECT Date 
FROM tblDate 
WHERE id = %1  =>  %1 is q.quoteId
```

Everything works fine, but I decided to add inputs that alternate the SQL request. For example, `c.Contact` can be "John"

```
WHERE c.Contact = 'John'
```

How about the `Date`? I can easily get `q.quoteId`, `c.Contact` and `q.Job` but I don't know how to make it work with Date too.

```
WHERE c.Contact = 'John' AND ...
```

Comment: What is the structure of `tblDate`?  Surely there is a `quoteId` or some other field you can join against?

Comment: Is there a foreign key on tblDate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another join (use INNER JOIN assuming each quote has a date value):

```
SELECT 
    q.quoteId, c.contact, q.job, d.Date
FROM 
    tblQuotes AS q INNER JOIN 
        tblClients AS c ON q.user = c.user INNER JOIN
            tblDate AS d on d.id = q.quoteId
```

You can then modify accordingly to specify any additional criteria using the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
    q.quoteId, c.contact, q.job, d.Date
FROM 
    tblQuotes AS q INNER JOIN 
        tblClients AS c ON q.user = c.user INNER JOIN
            tblDate AS d on d.id = q.quoteId
WHERE
    d.Contact = 'John'
```